# Eclipse is Marking File Path for VideoView as incorrect

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a VideoView here but Eclipse is saying `raw cannot be resolved to a verable` and `apw cannot be resolved to a variable` at line `videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(@raw/apw.avi));`

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(@raw/apw.avi));
    videoHolder.requestFocus();
    videoHolder.start();
```

Comment: it is marking the parse wrong as `not applicable for the arguement`

Comment: @user1956475 try with the solution I have posted.

Comment: @user1956475 I have posted answer please check it. It might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way :

```
Uri videouri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/apw");
videoHolder.setVideoURI(videouri);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must copy the video into your project's res/raw folder.
    It must be in a supported format (3gp, wmv, mp4 ) and named with lower case, numerics, underscores and dots in its filename: apw.mp4

When you work with this resource in code, you will reference through the generated R statics - it will have the file extension removed: R.raw.apw

```
VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.apw;
videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
videoHolder.requestFocus();
videoHolder.start();
```